# How to programmatically determine the currently connected database in Rails 7 using connects_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using Rails 7 with the new connects_to feature.
I have a primary database (:primary) and a secondary database (:secondary).
I've tried checking ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database in the console, but it doesn't seem to reflect the current connected database when using connects_to.
Also used the connection.current_database after call connects_to database: { writing: :primary, reading: :secondary }

I expect to find a way to determine,programmatically, which database (primary or secondary) is currently connected. At every query execution for SecondaryRecord < ApplicationReacord it will print the connected DB.

I've reviewed the Rails documentation and haven't found a clear solution.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config.name
```